# Are there considerable drawbacks to use Swift's ContiguousArray? If so, which are there?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, optimization

[Apple's ContiguousArray Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray) describes it as:

> The ContiguousArray type is a specialized array that always stores its elements in a contiguous region of memory. This contrasts with Array, which can store its elements in either a contiguous region of memory or an NSArray instance if its Element type is a class or @objc protocol.
> If your array’s Element type is a class or @objc protocol and you do not need to bridge the array to NSArray or pass the array to Objective-C APIs, using ContiguousArray may be more efficient and have more predictable performance than Array. If the array’s Element type is a struct or enumeration, Array and ContiguousArray should have similar efficiency.

To me this sounds like a ContiguousArray is always preferable to a regular Array since it has at least the same performance. Yet in my (perhaps too limited) experience with swift so far I've never seen anybody use a ContiguousArray instead of an Array and the description seems almost too good to be true.

I could not find any lists of drawbacks of ContiguousArrays online. I could imagine that while it is running faster, it has a less favourable memory usage than an array, but I can't find any information backing this. Can somebody with more understanding of the matter please help me to understand if there's a trade-off to expect when using ContiguousArrays?

Comment: I remember this discussion on swift forums long time ago, and basically the conclusion was: Array *is* automatically ContiniousArray, unless you have some NSArray interpolation. But even then: this looks to me as a premature optimization: if you have some array, say 100-1000 items, you won't feel the difference in performance. So why bother to use "specialized array" when you can use a normal with the same outcome? Only if you have performance issues with Array, then you may look at ContiniousArray as a way to improve performance. But not the only way either.

Comment: I would add that if there is a particular need for you to care about the way your array is stored in memory then I would consider not using the default array, `Array`.